# using cross validation for calculating specificity

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, make-scorer

I want to use cross-validation for calculating specificity. I found code for calculating accuracy, really, f1-score, and precision. but I couldn't found for specificity.
for example, the code for f1-score is like:

```
cross_val_score(SVC, X, y, scoring="f1", cv = 7)
```

or for precision is like:

```
cross_val_score(SVC, X, y, scoring="precision", cv = 7)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59396145/10495893, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33275461/10495893

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specifity is basically the True Negative Rate which is the same as the True Positive Rate (Recall)  but for the negative class

If you have a binary class, you should do the following

- Import the metric `recall_score` from `metrics` (details [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html#sklearn.metrics.recall_score)), and `make_scorer` function

  ```
  from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
  from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
  ```
- Then you generate your new scorer, defining for which class you are calculating recall (by default, the recall is calculated on the label=1)

  ```
  specificity = make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label=0)
  ```

The label 0 is usually the negative class in a binary problem.

```
print(cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10, specificity))
```

if you want the recall (True positive rate) you can do the same changing the class

```
sensitivity = make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label=1)
print(cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10, sensitivity))
```

Anyway you can make your custom scorer, if you need something more complex

[make_scorer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html)